# cocos2d: How to set a timer

Tags: iphone, cocos2d-iphone

I am developing an iPhone app using cocos2d and box2d.In this app i require to set a timer.
The timer will show the remaining time in hand of an player to reach destination...

how can i do that.....i have drawn a scene but no sure as i am beginner how to add timer..

thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use CCTimer.
Just like this:

```
float delay = 1.0; // Number of seconds between each call of myTimedMethod:
CCTimer *myTimer = [[CCTimer alloc] initWithTarget:self 
                             selector:@selector(myTimedMethod:) interval:delay]];
```

The method myTimedMethod: will get called then each second.

Comment: What is the advantage of a `CCTimer` over an `NSTimer`?

Comment: It uses cocos2d's internal scheduling mechanism. If I understand correctly it depends on which CCDirector type is used. The pro's and con's (if there are any) are probably mostly irrelevant in this case.

Comment: One big advantage is, that this timer gets paused when the game is paused, I think.

Comment: that and it's guaranteed to fire at a specific time within the update/render loop

Answer (score 18):

I would simply schedule a selector with an interval. This works in all CCNode based classes.

Schedule a selector triggered once per second:

```
[self schedule:@selector(timerUpdate:) interval:1];
```

This method gets called once per second:

```
-(void) timerUpdate:(ccTime)delta
{
  numSeconds++;
  // update timer here, using numSeconds
}
```

Parceval's method using CCTimer is ok too but you should prefer the static autorelease initializer like this:

```
CCTimer *myTimer = [CCTimer timerWithTarget:self
                                   selector:@selector(myTimedMethod:)
                                   interval:delay]];
```

Comment: This method is giving problem in v2.x. What is the replacement for this. Although the header file contains method but Xcode is giving error.

Comment: Same here. The there is no timerWithTarget or initWithTarget method anymore (iOS 7.1, Xcode 5.1.1.).